# How do you split full name to first and last names if some people only put their first name in the list? Using OpenPyxl

Tags: python, excel, split, slice, openpyxl

#What I have so far that doesn't work as I get the error: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1).

```
for cell in ws[fullname_column][1:]:
    firstname, lastname = cell.value.split()
    ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=firstname_column).value = firstname
    ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=lastname_column).value = lastname
```

Comment: Look for a space in the string first? How do you plan to differentiate people with two first names from people with two last names?

Comment: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: It isn't so much the splitting problem as problem arises when there's no last name in the full name list. My plan was to use whatever was put into there as a first name and leave the last name as blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in openpyxl you can get values by rows, something like this:

```
sheet[f"A{index}"].value)
```

So if column A is name and B is a surname, you can get values for both individually.

Here `index` is row number

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
firstname, lastname = cell.value.split()
```

You should

1. Split and check the length of the returned list.
2. If length is 1 then probably you only have 1st name
3. If length is 2 then u have both 1st and last name

Comment: Thats the problem in this case because some of the values are length=1 as they only put their first or last name in the cell. I want to split all length=1 into first name only and leave last name as blank but I don't know how to get around this.

Comment: Oh, so u can instead get values from rows by index.

Comment: correct but how would you go around split() when it can't split it if there's no last names available?

Comment: you don't need to split, check out my 2nd answer